# Ignore property from object if integer value is 0 in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

If integer property is 0 ignore it, from json object.

```
[JsonProperty("amount")]
public int Amount { get; set; }
```

I don't want to apply it globally in the application.

Comment: And your problem/question is?

Comment: Do you mean _"if I serialize an object of this class, and the `Amount` is zero, I don't want the `amount` to show up in the resulting JSON"_?

Comment: @CSharpie I am making an API call to third party system if in any case the Amount is assigned to 0 exclude the property amount from object while sending out the request.

Comment: `[DefaultValue(0)]
JsonProperty("fixed_period", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int FixedPeriod { get; set; }`

that code worked for me now thankyou all

Comment: @Aamir, in the above code fixed_period is the private property for FixedPeriod? can i just use [JsonProperty("FixedPeriod", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using the [Json-Ignore Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0#ignore-individual-properties).

The code would be:

```
[JsonProperty("amount")]
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
public int Amount { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just to add up, notice that this is System.Text.Json's JsonIgnore. For Newtonsoft, you can take a look at [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm)